# Browser hangs when navigating into profile pages using Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I want to be able to get the names of doctors from their profile pages. From the city page, I need to loop through the different doctor's links and then click on each link to go into the profile pages to then get the doctor's name.

Currently I am able to loop through the doctor's links from the city pages, however, when clicking the links to navigate into the specific profile pages, the browser hangs and times-out.

**See my actual code below:**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const scrapeWebWithPagination = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const baseUrl = 'https://doctor.webmd.com/providers/specialty/pediatrics/alabama/alabaster';
  const totalPages = 2;

  try {
    for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
      const url = i === 1 ? baseUrl : `${baseUrl}?pagenumber=${i}`;
      await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });

      await page.waitForSelector(".page-mb");

      // loop through all the doctors links
      const links = await page.evaluate(async () => {
          const links = [];

          const elements = await document.querySelectorAll(".prov-name");

          for (let el of elements) {
          const link = await el.href;

          links.push(link);
          }

          return links;
      });

      console.log({ links });


      // go inside each link to access doctors profile page
      const docPosts = [];

      for (let link of links) {
        await page.goto(link);

        await page.waitForSelector(".webmd-main");

        const docPost = await page.evaluate(async () => {
          return {
            title: await document.querySelector(".provider-full-name.loc-co-fname").textContent,
          };
        });

        docPosts.push(docPost);
      }

      console.log({ docPosts });
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error occurred:', error);
  } finally {
    await browser.close();
  }
};

scrapeWebWithPagination();
```

What's strange is that if I try this same code with this website (https://quotes.toscrape.com/) the code works fine.

**See the code below:**

```
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

  const scrapeWebWithPagination = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      defaultViewport: null,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const baseUrl = 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/';
    const totalPages = 2;

    try {
      for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
        const url = i === 1 ? baseUrl : `${baseUrl}/page/${i}`;
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
        

        // loop through all the doctors links
        const links = await page.evaluate(async () => {
          const links = [];
          
          const elements = await document.querySelectorAll(".quote .author + a");
          
          for (let el of elements) {
              const link = await el.href;

              links.push(link);
          }

          return links;
        });
        
        console.log({ links });
        
        
        // go inside each link to access doctors profile page
        const docPosts = [];
        
        for (let link of links) {
          await page.goto(link);
          
          await page.waitForSelector(".container");
          
          const docPost = await page.evaluate(async () => {
              return {
                  title: await document.querySelector(".author-title").textContent,
              };
          });
          
          docPosts.push(docPost);
        }
        
        console.log({ docPosts });
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error occurred:', error);
    } finally {
      await browser.close();
    }
  };

  scrapeWebWithPagination();
```

What could I be doing wrong? I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out why is not working on the doctors website. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: You have a number of unnecessary awaits. All the browser console code in `evaluate` is synchronous.